# How would I determine my search radius when conducting a Topographic Position Index in SAGA GIS?

Tags: geoprocessing, saga, tools, topography, indexing

When running the TPI tool in SAGA, I get this parameter-entry window:

[image]

Under the section highlighted in the red box, what do these parameters mean? Do the search/neighbourhood grouping parameters mean cells? What would the "standardize" section indicate? Would distance weighting also be recommended?

Answer (score 2):

It is good you started to work with TPI on SAGA, since it is rare software which cares TPI's scale-dependent nature. 
In the poster linked below you will find answers.

Andrew D. Weiss [Topographic Position and Landforms Analysis](http://www.jennessent.com/downloads/tpi-poster-tnc_18x22.pdf)

The above poster is in fact accessible from inside SAGA. On SAGA Manager Window, you would have already run `Topographic Position Index (TPI)` through `Tool Libraries | Terrain Analysis | Morphometry`. Then you can see *Description* on `Object Properties Window` which shows parameters setting, along with referenced papers including the link to the above *A.D.Weiss* poster.

Then remaining question would be Distance weighting. My personal recommendation is not to use it. More important part is how to find best scale (outer radius and inner radius; like a doughnut) which describes your subject best. Adding distance weighting complicate its interpretation and can be distracting.

Comment: Would you also know how to export the TPI Saga File into ArcMap while keeping all the data attached to the file so I can classify it? Right now I am only able to save them as image files, with no data and just the RGB values.

Comment: Without more details I cannot make clear answer, but it sounds like you have been trying to save your map (for instance `Menu | Map | Save as Image`), not your TPI grid. You can try (1) Save it as SAGA Grid by `Manager | Data | Grids` Right-click on your TPI Grid and `Save As` TPI.sgrd. (2) Convert sgrd file to asc by `Menu | Geoprocessing | File | Grid | Export | Export ESRI Arc/Info`. If this does not work, please open a new question.